# Unable to access API deployed via Docker-Compose

Tags: c#, docker-compose, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have a Dotnet6 WebAPI which requies a Postgres DB and I am trying to deploy them together using Docker-Compose.

However, when deployed, I am unable to access the WebAPI from Postman (I get a socket hang up error).
I believe it is a configuration problem with the WebAPI and not the docker-compose file, but I can't identify the issue.

My Docker compose file

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  postgres:
    command:
      - postgres
    container_name: database
    entrypoint:
      - docker-entrypoint.sh
    environment:
        { omitted for brevity }
    image: postgres
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - 5432:5432/tcp
    volumes:
      - 5e1d4bd6f1b3ac97725c260c3cecc9ac5c79b9c79b856c7eda3cd7047ad7702e:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  mywebapi:
    command:
      - -f
      - /dev/null
    container_name: mywebapi
    entrypoint:
      - tail
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
      - DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
    ports:
      - "5080:80"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    image: mywebapi:dev
    network_mode: bridge
    tty: true
    volumes:
        { omitted for brevity }
    working_dir: /app

volumes:
  5e1d4bd6f1b3ac97725c260c3cecc9ac5c79b9c79b856c7eda3cd7047ad7702e:
    external: true
```

Launchsettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "SimpleAuthenticationModule": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://+:5027"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
      "publishAllPorts": true
    }
  },
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://+:80",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  }
}
```

My dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SimpleAuthenticationModule/SimpleAuthenticationModule.csproj", "SimpleAuthenticationModule/"]
COPY ["SAM Shared/SAM Shared.csproj", "SAM Shared/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SimpleAuthenticationModule/SimpleAuthenticationModule.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SimpleAuthenticationModule"
RUN dotnet build "SimpleAuthenticationModule.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SimpleAuthenticationModule.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SimpleAuthenticationModule.dll"]
```

What is strange is that if I just deploy my WebAPI in a standalone docker container via docker CLI (not via docker-compose), then I can access it without issue.  But if I deploy as above, or even just alone in docker-compose then it doesn't work.
The container(s) come up OK and are running, just the WebAPI is not accessible.

Comment: Can you see the swagger from it? While in the docker?

Comment: @Camadas No, also not working.

Comment: Reading the compose
on the `depends_on:` put it like this
`depends_on:
    postgres:
        condition: service_healthy`

Then add this to the `postgre`
`healthcheck:
    test: ['CMD-SHELL', 'psql --username=usernameofpostgre --dbname postgres -c "select 1"']`
Since you told that the webapi alone is working but when you put it with postgre isn't, it could be this

Comment: No, sorry, I maybe should have been clearer.  When I deploy the WebApi via docker CLI (not docker-compose) then it works OK, but doesn't work in docker-compose.  Even if I remove the postgres DB (the containers start OK, but I can't access the webAPI port, the postgress DB can be access externally OK).

Comment: check the container log . ` docker log mywebapi` and see on which port your API is running. and also launchsettings.json is not used when deploying inside container so you can remove it from ques. and you can add which url you are trying to access ?

Comment: I can see "Now listening on: http://[::]:80" and I am trying to access "http://localhost:5080/api/Authentication"

Comment: According to the compose, you should access on the port `5080` since you making a `PortForward` on the docker is `80` but from your machine to access to it it must be `5080`
and what @CodingMytra told, is right, you don't need the `launchSettings.json` to start the API.

Comment: what port do you map when running as standalone docker container via docker CLI. i hope same ports what you given in docker-compose file.

Comment: After more investigation then it seems that the API app is actually not coming up correctly at all when deployed via Docker-compose.  I get no logs output at all in the docker container!  When built and deployed as docker (not via compose) then it all works fine.